# Truncate data frame column characters and update legend based on result in R

Tags: r, legend

I am writing an R script that incoorporates a data frame.
The data frame has the following look:

```
mydf <= read.csv('file', header = TRUE, sep=",")

mydf
....Prod  Date                   AVG
189 CA123 2012/07/24 14:32:35   0.2424     0.22     0.25     0.27
190 JK489 2012/08/25 18:29:08   0.2402     0.22     0.25     0.27
191 CA15K 2012/07/24 13:49:07   0.2427     0.22     0.25     0.27
192 JA45A 2012/07/22 02:32:40   0.2455     0.22     0.25     0.27
193 JA3HS 2012/07/24 22:26:25   0.2410     0.22     0.25     0.27
194 CA429 2012/08/28 10:36:16   0.2351     0.22     0.25     0.27
195 JK345 2012/07/25 07:11:24   0.2419     0.22     0.25     0.27
...
```

I am using this code to plot the data:

```
plot(Date,mydf$AVG,xlab='Date',ylab='AVG',main='title')
legend("topright", legend = c(" "," "), text.width = strwidth("1,000,000"), lty = 1:2, xjust = 1, yjust = 1, title = "Prods")
```

The plot is working fine, but I am unable to get the Legend formatting down. What I want to do is place a legend in the top right that will display each Prod as a different color data point on the graph; however, Prod also needs to be trucated and only count as the first two characters in the column.

I know I can access all the variables by running: `mydf$Prod', but is there a way to truncate each item in that frame reference to just two characters. I tried using round, but I am unable to perform any math operations, which makes sense.

Is there a way to truncate these variables and then paste them into the legend keeping the truncated format. The legend will need to be dynamic, because the Prod's are constantly changing, and I run the script on different files.

**One additional item:** Ideally, I would like this to be done with just the standard librarys. Im not currently using ggplot, or any other graphing library, as the graphs I am creating are simple.

Comment: For truncating strings, look at the `substr` function.

Comment: OK awesome. The substring function worked great. Is there a way to parse this into the legend, color coding each entry to match with each data point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
mydf$Labels = substr(mydf$Prod, 1, 2)
f = factor(mydf$Labels)
l = levels(f)
plot(mydf$Date, mydf$Avg, xlab="Date", ylab="Avg", col=f)
legend("topright", legend = l, fill = 1:length(l), title = "Prods")
```

Comment: This legend did not display the products substrings correctly. In fact, it didn't display a legend at all

Comment: I am not sure about the other parameters you have used like text.width. Can you check substr(myDF$prod, 1, 2) is what you are looking for? Also can you check only legend("topright", legend = substr(myDF$prod, 1, 2))?

Comment: I tried just `legend("topright", legend = substr(mydf#prod,1,2) and this time it just display all the trucations, including repeats. So there was about 300 entries for the legend, instead of just the three.